# What input pre-processing is required for TensorFlow Lite pre-trained models

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

TensorFlow Lite framework has some pre-trained models:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models

How do I know what pre-processing to input of the network is needed? (scale, mean values)

I'm talking about .pb file with FakeQuant* operation.

I need this to understand where those `min` and `max` parameters of FakeQuant* operation trained with pre-processing or not

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The std_value and mean_value correspond to how the float values of input during training map to the quantized ones during inference. The quantized model expects values from 0 to 255, but values during training could be any float value (i.e. [0.0f, 1.0f].
mean_value = the integer value [0, 255] that maps to float 0.0f.
std_value = 255 / [float_max - float_min]

Hope that helps!